# How to execute function in backends every x minutes

Tags: backend

This is my issue:

- I have an API which updates every 30 seconds the result displays on an endpoint
- I want to display the result on my web site for all visitors and so update it automatically every 30 seconds

I don't want each visitor to send a request on my API as it would overwhelm the API (and it is clearly not the right way to implement it I guess).

**Is there a way to send one request every 30 seconds from my web site backend to my API in order to display it for all visitors on the web site?**
Or maybe there is another smarter/efficient way to do it?

Another question I'm asking, **I want exactly the same "front" web site content for all users.** I mean, there would have requests from frontend to backend to have the information, but I don't want some users to have the information earlier as their requests would be few seconds before other users. I was thinking to "send requests based on GMT+1 hour for example", I don't know if it makes sense or if there is another way ?

N.B.: I'm using Wix services, maybe I would have to change and build my proper web site.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to send one request every 30 seconds from my website backend to my API in order to display it for all visitors on the website?

You could use realtime communication between your website and your backend server. For example Socket.IO or SignalR depends on the stack you are using. So instead of sending a call every 30 seconds, the API server would dispatch an event to all clients and tell them to update (or send the data along when you dispatch the event).

> I want exactly the same "front" website content for all users.

As for your second question, if you opt to use realtime communication to sync data between backend and frontend then there should be no need for having requests sent on a timer as your data is always updated actively from the server side.